# Regex to match multiple subdirectories in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, subdirectory

I am trying to build a Regex in Google analytics and would like your opinion on the result.

I want a Regex to match the following pages:

```
http://domain.com/thank-you/
http://domain.com/thank-you2/
http://domain.com/thank-you?=valid
http://domain.com/thank-you2=?valid
```

And the subdirectories like de, es, nl, hr, pr-br See the example below:

```
http://domain.com/de/thank-you/
http://domain.com/de/thank-you2/ etc.
```

This is the Regex that I have created:

```
(^/thank-you.*)|(/(de|es|nl|hr|pr\-br)/thank-you.*)
```

Does this look right to you? Thanks

Comment: You ask whether it looks right, but have you tested it yet? How does the result differ from what you expected (if it does)?

Comment: i think this `^(/(de|es|nl|hr|pr\-br)?/thank-you.*` would be enough.

Comment: @MattChampion I tested it and it shows results, but I tested another syntax too and it also showed results. I just wanted to get a second opinion on this.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's not enough because the ^ means that the regex matches only the URI that start with /de/es/nl/hr/pr\-br but not just /thank-you

Comment: @MihneaBoiangiu i make that part optional so it matches `/thank-you` also if it is present at the first. Did you check the regex that i posted?

Comment: @AvinashRaj your set up it's not correct, because what you built have a parenthesis there so it should be like this - ^(/de|es|nl|hr|pr\-br)?/thank-you.*
Basically it does the same thing as my RegEx from above. :)

Comment: yep i shorten your regex that 's all.

Comment: yeah thanks, I just wanted a second opinion on the syntax. both work ok :)